# How to get the entry value in Python tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So, i've been working on my first code, a weight converter to test what i learned, and im stuck trying to get the value of the entry. I've tried to use the '''get''' function, but it isn't working. Am i doing something wrong? Should i try to format it differently?

Here's the code for what i did so far (didn't do the code for the functions yet)

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Weight Conversion")

# Height and Width of the Main Window
height_ = 725
width_ = 625

exchange_values = {"pound": 2.20462, "ounce": 35.274, "dec_conv_value": 1000}

canvas = Canvas(root, height=height_, width=width_, bg="#80dfff")
canvas.pack()

frame = tkinter.Frame(root, bg="#ccffff")
frame.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.75)

label = Label(frame, text="Kilograms", bg="#ccffff")
label.pack()

entry = Entry(frame)
entry.pack()


def convert():

    weight_grams = kg * exchange_values['dec_conv_value']
    weight_kilotons = kg / exchange_values['dec_conv_value']
    weight_pound = kg * exchange_values['pound']
    weight_ounce = kg * exchange_values['ounce']



button_ = tkinter.Button(frame, text="Convert", bg="#e6ffff", relief=GROOVE)
button_.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean? What happens when you call it?

Comment: you shud use use `entry.get()` (in your case). So i think you should replace your `kg` variable with `entry.get()` cause i dont see any defining of `kg`

Answer (score 0):

You should do `entry_var.get()`.

This is a simple example:

```py
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Minimalistic Example")

label = Label(root, text="Function", bg="#ccffff")
label.pack()

def fnc():
    print(b1.get())


b1 = tkinter.Button(root, text="Convert", command=fnc)
b1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How do i do that? i'm trying to convert the value into a variable so that the button can do the calculations and print it, any thoughts on how i can do that? appreciate the help.

Comment: you shud use use `entry.get()` (in your case). So i think you should replace your `kg` variable with `entry.get()` cause i dont see any defining of `kg`

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a variable
Then put it on entry widget

```
kilo = IntVar() # for integer value or
kilo = StringVar() #for string value
entry=Entry( frame,textvar= kilo) 
entry.pack()

def convert():
    kilo.get()
```